# Do I need Microsoft authorization to support Xbox 360 controllers for a pc game?

Tags: xbox360, controllers

Do I need to pay Microsoft, or do I need some kind of license so I can support the xbox controller on a pc game? Or I just implement it and let people use their Xbox 360 controllers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you do not need authorization from Microsoft to support Xbox 360 controllers.

You can use the XInput API for free.

Comment: is the XInput API a package that is included with the Unity install, or do I have to download something?

Comment: I recommend using [InControl](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/incontrol-14695) or [Rewired](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676), which support XInput. Third-party plugins solve a lot of issues that Unity hasn't bothered to provide out of the box.

Comment: Note that showing images of the exact 360 controller or its exact buttons can technically fall under Microsoft copyrigh/trademark/trade dress, but if you make your own stylized assets for your button prompts and they're used purely for helping players play your game, not to imply official Microsoft endorsement, then I doubt you'd have any trouble in this area. I am not a lawyer however, so if you need legal advice be sure to verify this with a legal professional.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone,  this will help a lot. :)

Comment: Note that there is Xbox 360 artwork available under the [Microsoft Permissive License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MS-PL) you can use for in-game help screens and prompts that were released original for XNA Game Studio titles. You can still find them on a XNA Game Studio archive site: [Controller images](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Xbox-360-Controller-Images), [Button images](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Xbox-360-Controller-Button-Images).